# Some architecture and design guidance regarding PRISM and WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a few questions regarding WPF MVVM application development with PRISM framework:

1. Should modules in a modular application contain data access code ?
2. If modules depend on code present in an infrastructure project like the "Stock Trader RI" in the prism documentation does, wouldn't that cause tight coupling between those modules and the infra. project, aren't modules suppose to be self contained functionality !?
3. I like the DDD (Domain Driven Development) mythology that all code should depend on the business logic layer, thus no "dependency arrows" should go out of the BLL, instead they should go into the BLL (eg. the DAL depends on interfaces in the BLL and then you can use a DI Container to wire everything), and I think that the modules are the BLL of the application, so I don't want them depending on anything, can you achieve that in a modular PRISM app (how) ?

Comment: It might be useful if you were more specific about what you wanted to accomplish in your particular problem domain.  The loosest possible coupling would be to transfer a plain data `object`, but obviously that's not going to be very useful to your application unless you can give it some shape by casting it to some API such as a `ViewModel` class or an interface.

Comment: Also, you should read the Wikipedia article on loose coupling.  It says, *"Loose coupling occurs when the dependent class contains a pointer only to an interface, which can then be implemented by one or many concrete classes. The dependent class's dependency is to a "contract" specified by the interface; a defined list of methods and/or properties that implementing classes must provide. Any class that implements the interface can thus satisfy the dependency of a dependent class without having to change the class."*

Comment: @RobertHarvey I can't be more specific because i asked a more specific question lately but got no answer.i know interfaces impose contracts and provide loose coupling but DDD's view of dependency enables you to isolate BLL into re-usable libraries with public interfaces and then all other layers in your application depend on those. i wish i could provide an example but it wouldn't fit here. and if possible i would like your opinion on the first question particularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, since a Prism application is usually only made up of modules, then if you want data accessed in your application you will have to access it from the modules in some manner.
2. Managing dependencies is important. I try to examine what my module does in order to decide whether it makes sense for it to reference my infrastructure project or not. For example, if you were creating an event logging module, you might want to consider putting that interface in a common library that isn't your infrastructure project, because you may re-use that for other projects. However, I do not mind my project specific modules referencing the infrastructure project. The modules still allow me to enforce loose coupling, swap out modules at will to add or remove features, or swap the UI if I were to slice the application horizontally instead of vertically.
3. I'm not quite sure what you mean by not depending on "anything". I imagine they still depend on the .NET core libraries. So what about Prism? Is that allowed? If you are concerned about them referencing Prism or your infrastructure project you could always have your BLL code in separate DLLS that your modules reference and implement the model repositories, view model logic, and view logic inside of.

Comment: I mostly agree with your first answer, regarding the second if you put logging or authentication or other "Cross-Cutting Concern" in a shared library and made the BLL depend on that, wouldn't that create tight coupling, i think using an interception mechanism of a DI container would help a lot in this situation. now for the last part, you're right that the code should at least depend on the .NET framework or prism but i consider those to be "Stable dependencies" (they don't change quite often) according to Mark Seemann in his book Dependency Injection in .NET, and that's OK.

Comment: If you want your business logic to including logging, then it must reference a library that includes the interface, not necessarily the implementation. Since the interface for your logging is probably reusable, I may consider putting that in a library that is reusable within the organization. Either that, or it must go into the infrastructure project. The implementation could be elsewhere, as a separate module, for example, which you could try to keep it from having a reference to the infrastructure project if you desire it to not be dependent on that project.

Comment: thanks. i think you and i agree on the solution. but it seems i just don't like the way prism apps are composed. anyway that's a personal matter. so i will consider your answer a correct one.